# Php PDO OCI Driver installation using pecl

Tags: php, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to install the PDO driver for OCI.

When searching Google for pdo_oci I find the following URL:

https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_OCI

It displays this message at the top of the page:

> This package is not maintained anymore and has been superseded. Package has moved to channel http://www.php.net/pdo_oci, package ext/pdo_oci.

What does this message mean, how do I add this channel using pecl?

I've attempted to add that channel using `pear channel-discover php.net/pdo_oci`, but it doesn't seem to work.  I also can't find a channel.xml file for php.net/pdo_oci so I could try `pear channel-add channel.xml`.

Comment: There are a few options; in order to provide a helpful answer it would be good to know more details about your PHP installation. Did you use a pre-made package (e.g. on debian, `apt-get install php5…`), or compile PHP yourself?

Comment: Using RHEL6 with the Remi repos. 

2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 12 16:05:43 EST 2014 x86_64

Answer (score 7):

## EDIT

**If you already have php installed (from repository for example), you can compile only the PDO_OCI from PHP source (you need the instantclient installed)**

- [Download the PHP source](http://php.net/downloads.php) with same version that you have
  installed;
- Unzip;
- Change to directory
  **php-YOUR-VERSION/ext/pdo_oci**

Inside the pdo_oci folder, run these commands:

```
$ phpize  
$ ./configure --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,12.1  
$ make && make install  
$ echo "extension=pdo_oci.so" > /etc/php.d/pdo_oci.ini  
$ service httpd restart
```

This method will only create a pdo_oci.so in the PHP extensions folder, don't need to recompile entire PHP. You can do it with repositories versions of PHP, and can do it with any extension inside the **ext** folder in PHP source.

---

First, sorry for my bad english.

I had the same question, but I could already solve.

As the message says, this PECL extension is deprecated. You need to compile PHP from source with the PDO_OCI that is included in PHP Source.

I made this way in **CentOS 6.6**, with MySQL, Apache and InstantClient installed:

Install dependencies like

```
curl-devel
freetype-devel
libc-client
libc-client-devel
libjpeg-devel
libmcrypt-devel
libpng-devel
libtool-ltdl-devel
libxml2-devel
libXpm-devel
libc-client
libc-client-devel
libmcrypt-devel
libpng-devel
db4-devel

...And other prompted dependencies in the ./configure 
(always install the *-devel package too)
```

**Download the PHP Source**

```
$ wget http://ar2.php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
```

**Unzip downloaded file and change to folder**

```
$ tar -xzf php-5.6.10.tar.gz  
$ cd php-5.6.10
```

**Execute the *configure* command with the desired params (my example below)**

```
./configure \   
--prefix=/usr \  
--sysconfdir=/etc \  
--localstatedir=/var \  
--datadir=/usr/share/php \  
--mandir=/usr/share/man \  
--with-config-file-path=/etc \  
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d \  
--with-zlib \  
--enable-bcmath \  
--with-bz2 \  
--enable-calendar \  
--with-gdbm \  
--with-gmp \  
--enable-ftp \  
--with-gettext \  
--enable-mbstring \  
--with-readline \  
--with-apxs2 \  
--with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,12.1 \  
--enable-dba=shared \  
--with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock \  
--with-pdo-pgsql \ 
--with-mcrypt \  
--with-mhash \  
--with-curl \  
--with-gd \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-vpx-dir=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--with-t1lib=/usr \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \  
--enable-soap \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-xsl \
--with-tidy=/usr \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-shmop
```

If you see any error when running this command, you are probably missing some dependency (maybe a dependency that I have not mentioned).

**After run the configure command without errors**

```
$ make && make install
```

At this moment, PHP is already installed.
To certify, use the command below:

```
$ php -v
```

But before finishing, we need to make some adjustments...

**Copy php.ini to the correct directory**

```
### If you're on a development server    
$ cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini

### If you're on a production server
$ cp php.ini-production /etc/php.ini
```

**Open Apache config file to edit**

```
$ vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

**Add the following lines so that Apache interpret PHP (ignore if already have)**

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

**Restart Apache**

```
$ service httpd restart
```

Comment: Edited to include more details

Comment: thanks for this, worked for me (just the first bit, before the first divider)

Comment: There may be a bug on some distributions that results in `Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h` on configure. (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59450) Temp workaround: create a symlink before configure: `sudo ln -s /usr/include/php5/ /usr/include/php`

Comment: Thanks a lot man you saved my day! Works on Ubuntu 18.10 with php7.2-fpm :)

Comment: Great man!! You not saved my day, but my week! So long trying to fix the pecl install error for pdo_pgsql on Debian with PHP7.0.33. After reading your solution, I've downloaded official PHP7.0.33 source, transferred the ext/pdo_pgsql, compiled and bam...it worked! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

After installing the Oracle drivers, you can use this [this class here](https://github.com/taq/pdooci) and then you just need to change your PDO connection from something like

```
$pdo = new PDO("oci:dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8", "user", "password");
```

to

```
$pdo = new PDOOCI\PDO("mydatabase", "user", "password");
```

The rest should work exactly the same as if you were using a PDO object.